# No longer getting the expected default values from nrfl2401 radio module

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, spi, embedded, nrf24l01

So I've been playing around with nrfl2401 and I see I am no longer getting the expected default value when I read the configuration register. The default value is `0x08` and I get `0x20`. I have tried resetting the device by disconnecting the wires and plugging back in to no avail. Even though I writing `0x08` to the configuration register didn't help in terms of value remaining maintained and not getting set to `0x20`.

Here's the config register.
[image]

Here's the capture.

[image]

Comment: did you actually read 0x08 before?

Comment: What has changed? Loose wires? Reset pin?

Comment: @jsotola yes. I was reading 0x08 before

Comment: @Justme there's no reset pin.

Comment: Ok, but there sure is powerdown and chip enable pins.

Comment: not power down, but yeah CE

Comment: one thing that has crossed my mind is that maybe reading the bit 5 reflects the state of the TX_DS interrupt and the interrupt has occurred .... what happens if you read the register immediately the second time?

Comment: i don't see interrupt occurring given I haven't even started the transmission.